# Change the simulator language

Tags: xcode, cucumber, appium, appium-ios

I need to test my application against many simulator with different language settings. 
For this, I set appium desired capabilities in the terminal by running:
➜  appium --language 'fr'
in order to set the language of my simulator to "fr".
I tried also another method by creating different profiles in my cucumber.yml configuration file.
Both methods are crashing my simulator(Please see logs below).
Note: I'm using
 appium v1.5.1
 MAC OS 10.11.4
 Xcode v7.0.1
 cucumber v2.3.3
 ruby v2.3.0
 Any ideas please how can I resolve this issue?

```
~ appium --language 'fr' 
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.1 (REV d183ff8065aafd3def71f9c9c728a3a92c1c4742)
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   language: 'fr'
[Appium] Deprecated server args:
[Appium]   --language => --default-capabilities '{"language":"fr"}'
[Appium] Default capabilities, which will be added to each request unless overridden by desired capabilities:
[Appium]   language: 'fr'
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 6s","app":"/Users/admin/Desktop/mbb_test_lang/mbb-ios.app"}}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 6s","app":"/Users/admin/Desktop/mbb_test_lang/mbb-ios.app"},null,null,null]
[Appium] Creating new IosDriver session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'iPhone 6s'
[Appium]   app: '/Users/admin/Desktop/mbb_test_lang/mbb-ios.app'
[Appium]   language: 'fr'
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 255d49e9-bd39-4eec-aad3-71e34319a924
[debug] [iOS] Not auto-detecting udid.
[BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/admin/Desktop/mbb_test_lang/mbb-ios.app'
[debug] [iOS] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
[debug] [iOS] Cleaned up instruments socket /var/folders/tf/cts_89gj4ld8c0n48_xjsyt40000gn/T/instruments_sock
[debug] [iOS] Setting Xcode version
[debug] [iOS] Xcode version set to 7.0.1
[debug] [iOS] Setting iOS SDK Version
[debug] [iOS] iOS SDK Version set to 9.0
[debug] [iOS] Checking whether instruments supports our device string
[debug] [Instruments] Getting list of devices instruments supports
[debug] [Instruments] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
[debug] [Instruments] Available devices: Apple Watch - 38mm (2.0) [7BCFC41E-A8E3-45C6-B9CE-11BDB3F9BF8E],Apple Watch - 38mm (2.0) [2063DC10-F889-4D1C-AA90-8D32FA925152],iPad 2 (9.0) [CE07BC04-A6CE-4213-B9A3-CC4D6463788D],iPad Air (9.0) [7B765DDC-FC32-46D1-B37F-FEA7D29888B6],iPad Air 2 (9.0) [459DCCB6-B65D-4148-A570-3B8270140219],iPad Retina (9.0) [97790AC6-1817-4390-ADFA-C907DAD047D7],iPhone 4s (9.0) [6023C32D-46F2-4570-8C25-7312930AE267],iPhone 5 (9.0) [FC288EFD-D953-41C1-99A1-9FC5C733FF98],iPhone 5s (9.0) [C05E7744-2A6A-48AA-94B7-603FB84F38A7],iPhone 6 (9.0) [B51E5E51-B8A0-425D-AB5D-12A829DE0EE0],iPhone 6 (9.0) [7E249D0E-4C38-401F-AE20-85453876DEB6],iPhone 6 Plus (9.0) [BEA8193C-F798-4B4C-A675-2BD3EB67C8BA],iPhone 6 Plus (9.0) [12724A1C-6A86-4279-B560-F205BA3A8933],iPhone 6s (9.0) [34B94AC9-69AA-4D68-8A02-18C98D53844C],iPhone 6s Plus (9.0) [946A4044-C5F7-4352-A77C-5E34356986A2],iPhone 6s Plus (9.0) [BE929090-9A8A-472E-B941-1A7F2192A6C1],iPhone 6s Plus (9.0) + Apple Watch - 42mm (2.0) [25B3E12D-5347-4BCA-8832-EC4E923A8FAB]
[iOSSim] Retrieving device name string for Xcode version 7.0.1
[debug] [iOSSim] Getting device string from options: {"deviceName":"iPhone 6s","platformVersion":"9.0","forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false}
[debug] [iOSSim] Fixing device. Changed from 'iPhone 6s' to 'iPhone 6s (9.0) ['
[debug] [iOSSim] Final device string is 'iPhone 6s (9.0) ['
[debug] [iOS] iOS sim UDID is 34B94AC9-69AA-4D68-8A02-18C98D53844C
[iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 7.0.1
[debug] [iOS] Parsed app 'Localizable.strings'
[debug] [ios-app-utils] Getting bundle ID from app
[iOS] Extracted bundleID: bnp.be.mbb-ios from app: /Users/admin/Desktop/mbb_test_lang/mbb-ios.app
[debug] [iOS] Creating instruments
[debug] [UIAuto] Preparing bootstrap code
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.6.0/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/var/folders/tf/cts_89gj4ld8c0n48_xjsyt40000gn/T/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"oneByOne"}
...bug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-0f443b56dc25b66c.js
[debug] [UIAuto] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-0f443b56dc25b66c.js
[debug] [iOS] User specified default device, letting instruments launch it
[debug] [iOS] Running ios sim reset flow
[debug] [iOS] Killing the simulator
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators
[debug] [iOS] Cleaning sim state.
[debug] [iOSSim] Cleaning app data files for 'mbb-ios.app', 'bnp.be.mbb-ios'
[iOSSim] Attempted to get an app path from a fresh simulator quickly launching the sim to populate its directories
[debug] [iOSSim] Attempting to launch and quit the simulator, to create directory structure
[debug] [iOSSim] Will launch with Safari? false
[iOSSim] Starting simulator with command: open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app --args -CurrentDeviceUDID 34B94AC9-69AA-4D68-8A02-18C98D53844C
[iOSSim] Tailing simulator logs until we encounter the string "System app "com.apple.springboard" finished startup"
[iOSSim] We will time out after 60000ms
[debug] [iOSSim] Waiting and extra 2000ms for the simulator to really finish booting
[debug] [iOSSim] Done waiting extra time for simulator
[iOSSim] Simulator booted in 20303ms
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators
[debug] [iOSSim] Building bundle path map
[debug] [iOSSim] Building bundle path map
[debug] [iOSSim] Could not find app directories to delete. It is probably not installed
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing any simulator daemons for 34B94AC9-69AA-4D68-8A02-18C98D53844C
[iOSSim] Cleaning simulator 34B94AC9-69AA-4D68-8A02-18C98D53844C
[debug] [iOS] No simulator directories found.
[debug] [iOSSim] Attempting to launch and quit the simulator, to create directory structure
[debug] [iOSSim] Will launch with Safari? false
[debug] [iOS] Setting locale information
[iOSSim] Starting simulator with command: open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app --args -CurrentDeviceUDID 34B94AC9-69AA-4D68-8A02-18C98D53844C
[debug] [iOSSim] New language: fr
[debug] [iOSSim] Writing new locale plist data
[debug] [iOS] Locale was updated. Stopping simulator.
[debug] [iOS] Killing the simulator
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators
[debug] [iOS] No iOS / app preferences to set
[debug] [iOSLog] Starting iOS 9.0 simulator log capture
[debug] [iOSLog] System log path: /Users/admin/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/34B94AC9-69AA-4D68-8A02-18C98D53844C/system.log
[debug] [iOS] Not pre-launching simulator
[debug] [iOS] Starting UIAutoClient, and launching Instruments.
[debug] [UIAuto] Instruments socket server started at /var/folders/tf/cts_89gj4ld8c0n48_xjsyt40000gn/T/instruments_sock
[debug] [Instruments] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to launch instruments, this is try #1
[Instruments] Launching instruments
[iOSSim] Tailing simulator logs until we encounter the string "System app "com.apple.springboard" finished startup"
[iOSSim] We will time out after 60000ms
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to run app on iPhone 6s (9.0) [
[Instruments] On xcode 7.0+, instruments-without-delay does not work, skipping instruments-without-delay
[debug] [Instruments] Found Insruments-Without-Delay: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7
[debug] [Instruments] Spawning instruments with command: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /var/folders/tf/cts_89gj4ld8c0n48_xjsyt40000gn/T/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPhone 6s (9.0) [" /Users/admin/Desktop/mbb_test_lang/mbb-ios.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-0f443b56dc25b66c.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/tf/cts_89gj4ld8c0n48_xjsyt40000gn/T/appium-instruments'
[debug] [Instruments] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
[debug] [Instruments] [INST] Waiting for device to boot...
[debug] [iOSSim] Waiting and extra 2000ms for the simulator to really finish booting
[UIAuto] Instruments is ready to receive commands
[debug] [iOS] Instruments launched. Starting poll loop for new commands.
[debug] [iOS] Setting bootstrap config keys/values
[debug] [UIAuto] Socket data received (2 bytes)
[debug] [UIAuto] Got a result when we were not expecting one! Ignoring it
[debug] [UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: target = $.target();
au = $;
$.isVerbose = true;

[debug] [iOSSim] Done waiting extra time for simulator
[iOSSim] Simulator booted in 21395ms
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators
```

Comment: someone can help me on that please?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting "**force device language option**" in appium, and try using a different simulator if crashing continues

Comment: I'm launching appium using the terminal.
According to the release note of v1.5.1 of appium: it says "Desired capabilities language and locale added"
Any idea how can i set it through capabilities in appium.txt file?

Comment: To set language in appium.txt you need to just add ```language: 'fr'``` there.

Comment: The issue is related to appium 1.5.1 and it has been resolved.
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6435

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification. Without `language` capability does the simulator work correctly?

Comment: It picks default language, which I guess is `EN`