# Desired capabilities not working with Appium V1.5.1

Tags: ruby, ios-simulator, appium

Did anyone use Desired capabilities with Appium V 1.5.1?
It is supported with Appium V1.5.1 but it's crashing on iOS simulator.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: can you share your appium server logs please.

Comment: Can you share your test scripts code what you are setting in DesireCapabilities

Comment: This is my desired capabilities:
[caps]
platformName = "iOS"
deviceName = "iPhone 6s"
app = "./mbb-ios.app"
autoDismissAlerts = true
language = "fr"

Comment: @SadikAli
Please refer to this issue, to get more information about my server logs
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769291/change-the-simulator-language/36787972#36787972

Comment: anyone can help on this?